# How to use zookeeper.net library in a .net core application

Tags: .net, .net-core, apache-zookeeper

The zookeeper.net is a library to work with zookeeper in a .net framework application, I can use it to connect the zookeeper to a .net core application, I can still install the zookeeper.net library, but when I run the code that connect zookeeper, I just got the following exception.

FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.

the code I wrote is :

```
 using (ZooKeeper zk = new ZooKeeper("127.0.0.1:2181", new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 50000), new Watcher()))
        {
            var stat = zk.Exists("/root", true);
```

Is there a way that I can fix this? or I just can not use this library in .net core?

Answer (score 0):

the zookeeper.net is build for .net framework. Currenlty we can not use it in a .net core application. But we can use the zookeeperNetEx to work with zookeeper.